# J2ME MIdlet Application Signing Issue

Tags: java, java-me, ssl-certificate, midlet, midp-2.0

I have developed j2me application.The application access files using file-connection api extensively, so purchased  certificate from symantec (Veri sign)to avoid file permission problems 
And signed the JAD file successfully.

Problem:-
On deploying this jad file on Blackberry curve and getting error 
909 Application authentication failure 2-142 MIDlet certificate chain error.
On deploying on Symbian N85 throws error as certificate error contact application supplier
but,despite root certificate installed on phone. 
cross verified serial number and everyting is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved.

Problem was that old mobiles use sha1 algorithm , but code signing authority issued certificates are default sha2. You need to explicitly request them to down grade the certificate to sha1 while applying for code signing (CSR).

And after signing your j2me midlet, Verify that there are 4 certificate chains
using this cmd:- `java -jar  JadTool.jar -showcert -all -inputjad your_Jad_fileName.jad`